# Are there instances where the density matrix is singular?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, singularities, density-operator, quantum-measurements

Are there instances where the density matrix is singular?  Can there be cases where a measurement projection onto the density matrix gives a singular matrix?

Comment: what do you mean with "singular" here? Are you referring to it being singular (i.e. non-invertible) as a matrix, or to something else?

Comment: Non-invertible.  Along similar lines, are there null vectors?

Comment: so then you already got an answer to that I believe. E.g. $|0\rangle\!\langle0|$ is nonsingular. The other points seem to be separate questions that should be asked separately (probably on math.SE rather than here)

Comment: I believe the previous comment argues that |0⟩⟨0| is singular.  Not following this argument as the eigenvalues do not appear in the density matrix.

Comment: sorry, yes, I meant that $|0\rangle\!\langle0|$ is singular, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\{|0\rangle ,|1\rangle\}$$  be a basis of the system to describe (e.g. a spin 1/2 system). Let the state of the system be $$|\Psi\rangle = |0\rangle.$$

Then the density matrix of the system is not invertible (since it has the eigenvalue 0 amongst others).

In practice, for most physical systems in thermodynamic equilibrium the density matrix is non-invertible since states which lie high in energy are not occupied (for the energy going to infinity), therefore the matrix has eigenvalues which are 0, which means the matrix is non-invertible.